# Can You Help Identify This Tool? Assuming It's 1800s!

Tags: tools, identify-a-tool

My grandfather was gifted this tool and we're trying to identify what it is. It has no unique markings other than the portion where engraved "US." It has a rivet on it, and that's as far as we know regarding facts. We assume 1800s, based on the second tool that also has no information and is only stamped with "US." Thank you so much[image]

Comment: It's an early competitor to the Swiss Army knife. One end is a spark-plug feeler gauge, the other is for extracting boy scouts from horse's hooves. ;) [Sorry, no, I've no clue]

Answer (score 26):

This is a **combination tool** for [Springfield Model 1892–99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springfield_Model_1892%E2%80%9399) Krag–Jørgensen rifles, the US army service rifle introduced in 1894 and phased out after 1903.

The specimen that you own is missing the rivet. Examples: [1](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/s-model-1897-combination-tool-krag-442287996) and [2](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/superb-m1897-us-springfield-krag-screwdriver-combo).

> (The) tool was carried in a compartment of the leather cartridge box. These tools were packed four for every twenty Carbines or Rifles shipped from the Arsenal.

Its successor, the [M1903 Springfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M1903_Springfield) rifle, has a [slightly different](https://www.lodgewood.com/US-M1903-Springfield-Combination-Tool--Variant-3_p_1989.html) combination tool. Thanks to Yorik for identifying the exact model!

Comment: better match ( Tool shipped with US Springfield Krag Carbine and Rifle1897 ) : https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/s-model-1897-combination-tool-krag-442287996

Comment: Yep, that's the one :)

Comment: @Yorik Do you want to start a second answer or should I edit this one into the above?

Comment: go ahead, its all yours

Comment: Added some extra background info as well. Although Wikipedia may not necessarily be complete, the entry there does not mention the existence of an M1897 model, so I've left the designation as *"1892-1899"*.